# How to produce an infinite binary tree?

Tags: haskell, tree, binary-tree

I'm asked to implement a function for the following binary tree:

```
data BinaryTree a = Nil | BNode a (BinaryTree a) (BinaryTree a)
```

The function I need to implement should produces a full, symmetric, infinite, binary tree of `a`'s, and should have the signature:

```
infTree :: a -> BinaryTree a
```

How can I implement it?

Comment: `tr a = BNode a (tr a) (tr a)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a circular reference where both of the child nodes **are** the parent node.

```
infTree :: a -> BinaryTree a
infTree x = tree
  where
    tree = BNode x tree tree
```

This is the same way the [`repeat`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:repeat) function is implemented:

```
repeat :: a -> [a]
repeat x = xs where xs = x : xs
```

Comment: could you please explain why this tree is infinite?

Comment: @tal If you tried to find the number of nodes in this tree, it would result in an infinite loop because it never reaches a `Nil`.

Comment: Due to the self-referential nature of the value, it's an infinite tree *encoded* as a single node in memory.

Comment: @tal if you'd enumerate the node values of the `infTree x` tree in a breadth-first fashion you'd get the never ending list of `x`s.

Comment: Or: `infTree x = fix (join (BNode x))`, which simplifies to `infTree = fix . join . BNode`